# How can I load DOM tree from index.php

Tags: php

I have an "index.php" locally which generates a web page including a table. What I want is to write another php file, parse the web page and to get the table content. So I use

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile("index.php");
```

But when I try to output:

```
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

The content is not html format at all. I mean it even does not have "html" or "body" tags. The "echo" just output the code in my "index.php". Could someone help me figure it out?

Comment: `loadHTMLFile()` doesn't execute PHP. You need to go through the server to get the resulting HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is only executed when the file is loaded through the webserver, not when it's read as a local file. So give a URL:

```
$dom->loadHTMLFile("http://localhost/path/to/index.php");
```

Replace `/path/to` with the correct URL path for the directory containing the `index.php`.

You could also use `shell_exec()` to execute the PHP script:

```
$html = shell_exec("php index.php");
$dom->loadHTML($html);
```

Comment: Hi Barmar, it actually worked! But I have a question. Why doesn't it work if i just replace it with "localhost/index.php"? Why is the "http://" necessary?

Comment: Actually I just test it by using "php OutputContent.php" in which I echo the content returned by loadHTMLFile. If I input my php file path in firefox, it does not output anything. Is there any difference?

Comment: The `php` command executes PHP code just like the webserver does.